# How to build and link to CGLM from Zig with or without SIMD intrinsics

Tags: sse, mingw-w64, glm-math, intrinsics, zig

I would like to link and use cglm C library. I'm working on windows without msvc (so targeting gnu C ABI) with Zig 0.7.1 and Zig 0.8.0 (master) without any luck.

I have been able to build CGLM static library from Zig build.zig but no luck linking against it from Zig program as CGLM SIMD intrinsics optimizations errors are reported.

```
const Builder = @import("std").build.Builder;

pub fn build(b: *Builder) void {
    // Standard target options allows the person running `zig build` to choose
    // what target to build for. Here we do not override the defaults, which
    // means any target is allowed, and the default is native. Other options
    // for restricting supported target set are available.
    const target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});

    // Standard release options allow the person running `zig build` to select
    // between Debug, ReleaseSafe, ReleaseFast, and ReleaseSmall.
    const mode = b.standardReleaseOptions();

    // cglm
    const cglmLibBasePath = "vendor/cglm/";
    const cglmFiles = &[_][]const u8{ 
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/euler.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/affine.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/io.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/quat.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/cam.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/vec2.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/vec3.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/vec4.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/mat2.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/mat3.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/mat4.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/plane.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/frustum.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/box.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/project.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/sphere.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/ease.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/curve.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/bezier.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/ray.c",
        cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/affine2d.c",
    };
    const cglmLib = b.addStaticLibrary("cglm", null);
    cglmLib.setBuildMode(mode);
    cglmLib.setTarget(target);
    cglmLib.defineCMacro("CGLM_STATIC");
    cglmLib.defineCMacro("WIN32");
    cglmLib.addIncludeDir(cglmLibBasePath ++ "src/");
    for (cglmFiles) |cglmFile| {
        cglmLib.addCSourceFile(cglmFile, &[_][]const u8 { 
            "-std=c11",
            "-Wall",
            "-Werror",
            "-O3",
        });
    }    
    cglmLib.linkLibC();
    cglmLib.install();

    const exe = b.addExecutable("app-zig-cglm", "src/main.zig");
    exe.setBuildMode(mode);
    exe.setTarget(target);  
    // cglm
    exe.linkLibrary(cglmLib);
    exe.addSystemIncludeDir(cglmLibBasePath ++ "include/");
    // C and win32
    exe.linkLibC();
    exe.install();
    

    const run_cmd = exe.run();
    run_cmd.step.dependOn(b.getInstallStep());
    if (b.args) |args| {
        run_cmd.addArgs(args);
    }

    const run_step = b.step("run", "Run the app");
    run_step.dependOn(&run_cmd.step);
}
```

When I try to build/run the exe with the generated library linked then the following error is reported (similar in both Zig versions 0.7.1 and 0.8.0 master) Ex from 0.7.1 Zig version.

```
alagt@LAPTOP-HS5L5VEH MINGW64 /c/Dev/Projects/test-bed/app-zig-cglm (master)
$ zig build -Dtarget=x86_64-windows-gnu
.\zig-cache\o\1bc9e6dc93c2ab6590b8006381a9000e\cimport.zig:4255:26: error: unable to translate function
pub const glm_mul_sse2 = @compileError("unable to translate function"); // C:\Dev\Projects\test-bed\app-zig-cglm\vendor\cglm\include\cglm/simd/sse2/affine.h:17:1
                         ^
.\zig-cache\o\1bc9e6dc93c2ab6590b8006381a9000e\cimport.zig:4264:5: note: referenced here
    glm_mul_sse2(m1, m2, dest);
    ^
.\zig-cache\o\1bc9e6dc93c2ab6590b8006381a9000e\cimport.zig:657:20: error: unable to resolve typedef child type
pub const __m128 = @compileError("unable to resolve typedef child type"); // C:\Dev\Tools\zig-0.7.1\lib\include\xmmintrin.h:17:15
                   ^
.\zig-cache\o\1bc9e6dc93c2ab6590b8006381a9000e\cimport.zig:1255:48: note: referenced here
pub fn _mm_store_ps(arg___p: [*c]f32, arg___a: __m128) callconv(.C) void {
                                               ^
.\zig-cache\o\1bc9e6dc93c2ab6590b8006381a9000e\cimport.zig:3557:5: note: referenced here
    _mm_store_ps(&dest[@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 0))], _mm_load_ps(&mat[@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 0))]));
    ^
app-zig-cglm...The following command exited with error code 1:
C:\Dev\Tools\zig-0.7.1\zig.exe build-exe C:\Dev\Projects\test-bed\app-zig-cglm\src\main.zig C:\Dev\Projects\test-bed\app-zig-cglm\zig-cache\o\dfacf78e7514990119de31b967d43202\cglm.lib --library c --cache-dir C:\Dev\Projects\test-bed\app-zig-cglm\zig-cache --global-cache-dir C:\Users\alagt\AppData\Local\zig --name app-zig-cglm -target x86_64-windows-gnu -isystem C:\Dev\Projects\test-bed\app-zig-cglm\vendor\cglm\include --enable-cache
error: the following build command failed with exit code 1:
C:\Dev\Projects\test-bed\app-zig-cglm\zig-cache\o\64a99c599e98cac00a19cffa57c71a68\build.exe C:\Dev\Tools\zig-0.7.1\zig.exe C:\Dev\Projects\test-bed\app-zig-cglm C:\Dev\Projects\test-bed\app-zig-cglm\zig-cache C:\Users\alagt\AppData\Local\zig -Dtarget=x86_64-windows-gnu
```

The unable to resolve line from avxintrin.h is the following

```
typedef float __m128 __attribute__((__vector_size__(16), __aligned__(16)));
```

I would like to know if C libraries using intrinsics can work as of now and if not I would like a way to disable the intrinsics features sse/avx/... from the build.zig so the CGLM can be built and linked without SIMD optimizations.

**Edit (Disabled SIMD features from build.zig)**

I have dug a bit on the lib/zig/std/build.zig to know how to disable SIMD features and finally I was able to disable with following code on my build.zig

```
var target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});
    target.cpu_features_sub = x86.featureSet(&[_]x86.Feature{
        x86.Feature.avx,
        x86.Feature.avx2,
        x86.Feature.avx512bf16,
        x86.Feature.avx512bitalg,
        x86.Feature.avx512bw,
        x86.Feature.avx512cd,
        x86.Feature.avx512dq,
        x86.Feature.avx512er,
        x86.Feature.avx512f,
        x86.Feature.avx512ifma,
        x86.Feature.avx512pf,
        x86.Feature.avx512vbmi,
        x86.Feature.avx512vbmi2,
        x86.Feature.avx512vl,
        x86.Feature.avx512vnni,
        x86.Feature.avx512vp2intersect,
        x86.Feature.avx512vpopcntdq,
        x86.Feature.sse,
        x86.Feature.sse_unaligned_mem,
        x86.Feature.sse2,
        x86.Feature.sse3,
        x86.Feature.sse4_1,
        x86.Feature.sse4_2,
        x86.Feature.sse4a,
        x86.Feature.ssse3,
    });
```

**State:**

Now I'm able to build (without SIMD optimizations what is not ideal) and link CGLM lib from zig code but really concerning problem arise as the code calling standard C tanf function is computing really wrong results.

Following the zig code generated for the glm_perspective function.

```
pub fn glm_perspective(arg_fovy: f32, arg_aspect: f32, arg_nearVal: f32, arg_farVal: f32, arg_dest: [*c]vec4) callconv(.C) void {
    var fovy = arg_fovy;
    var aspect = arg_aspect;
    var nearVal = arg_nearVal;
    var farVal = arg_farVal;
    var dest = arg_dest;
    var f: f32 = undefined;
    var @"fn": f32 = undefined;
    glm_mat4_zero(dest);
    f = (1 / tanf((fovy * 0.5)));
    @"fn" = (1 / (nearVal - farVal));
    dest[@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 0))][@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 0))] = (f / aspect);
    dest[@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 1))][@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 1))] = f;
    dest[@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 2))][@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 2))] = ((nearVal + farVal) * @"fn");
    dest[@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 2))][@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 3))] = -1;
    dest[@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 3))][@intCast(c_uint, @as(c_int, 2))] = (((2 * nearVal) * farVal) * @"fn");
}
```

The result of executing the f = (1 / tanf((fovy * 0.5))); line with arg_fovy = 0.785398185 (45 deg in radians) is **returning 134217728.** which is just totally wrong. Correct result should be approx. **2.4142134**.

VSCode cppvsdbg do not allow me to step into the tanf to understand what could be wrong with the tanf implementation.

**Edit (building and compiling min C code with Zig compiler):**

I have compiled a min C case using math tanf and built with Zig builder mechanism.

build.zig

```
const Builder = @import("std").build.Builder;
const x86 = @import("std").Target.x86;

pub fn build(b: *Builder) void {
    // Standard target options allows the person running `zig build` to choose
    // what target to build for. Here we do not override the defaults, which
    // means any target is allowed, and the default is native. Other options
    // for restricting supported target set are available.
    var target = b.standardTargetOptions(.{});    
    target.cpu_features_sub = x86.featureSet(&[_]x86.Feature{
        x86.Feature.avx,
        x86.Feature.avx2,
        x86.Feature.avx512bf16,
        x86.Feature.avx512bitalg,
        x86.Feature.avx512bw,
        x86.Feature.avx512cd,
        x86.Feature.avx512dq,
        x86.Feature.avx512er,
        x86.Feature.avx512f,
        x86.Feature.avx512ifma,
        x86.Feature.avx512pf,
        x86.Feature.avx512vbmi,
        x86.Feature.avx512vbmi2,
        x86.Feature.avx512vl,
        x86.Feature.avx512vnni,
        x86.Feature.avx512vp2intersect,
        x86.Feature.avx512vpopcntdq,
        x86.Feature.sse,
        x86.Feature.sse_unaligned_mem,
        x86.Feature.sse2,
        x86.Feature.sse3,
        x86.Feature.sse4_1,
        x86.Feature.sse4_2,
        x86.Feature.sse4a,
        x86.Feature.ssse3,
    });
    

    // Standard release options allow the person running `zig build` to select
    // between Debug, ReleaseSafe, ReleaseFast, and ReleaseSmall.
    const mode = b.standardReleaseOptions();

    const exeC = b.addExecutable("app-c", "src/main.c");
    exeC.setBuildMode(mode);
    exeC.setTarget(target);    
    // C and win32
    exeC.linkLibC();
    exeC.install();
    

    const run_cmd = exeC.run();
    run_cmd.step.dependOn(b.getInstallStep());
    if (b.args) |args| {
        run_cmd.addArgs(args);
    }

    const run_step = b.step("run", "Run the app");
    run_step.dependOn(&run_cmd.step);
}
```

src/main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    float fovDeg = (argc == 1 ? 45.0f : 50.0f);
    while (1) {
        float fovRad = fovDeg * (M_PI / 180.0f);
        float tanFov = tanf(fovRad);
        fprintf(stdout, "fovDeg=%f, fovRad=%f, tanFov=%f\n", fovDeg, fovRad, tanFov);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I build without SIMD exclusions or just set target as native the code executes correctly with the expected results.

**$ zig build -Dtarget=native-windows-gnu run -- 1**

```
fovDeg=50.000000, fovRad=0.872665, tanFov=1.191754
```

If I build with the SIMD exclusions and execute it then tanf returns 0

**$ zig build -Dtarget=x86_64-windows-gnu run -- 1**

```
fovDeg=50.000000, fovRad=0.872665, tanFov=0.000000
```

**Current status**

It seems to me that

- zig mingw64 or msvcrt do not support basic math functions and has floating point errors with x86_64 arch SIMD features disabled.
- Zig mingw64 do not support SIMD C code.
- CGLM can't be compiled by Zig in a workable manner.

If anybody can bring some light in case I'm missing something it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I misunderstand your problem but this worked for me with no errors. Add to your build.zig:

```
exe.addIncludeDir("path_to_your_cglm/cglm/include");
exe.addLibPath("path_to_your_cglm/cglm/win/Release");

exe.linkSystemLibrary("cglm");
```

Also, the Discord and reddit Zig communities are very active so consider posting there. Have a look at this page: https://github.com/ziglang/zig/wiki/Community.
There is also the [Zig Forum](https://zigforum.org/).

Comment: What I'm trying to do is build from Zig build system and not only using Zig cross compiler and importing the C header directly in Zig using the native Zig C-translation. So I don't need to depend on cmake build system.